# Could not load file or assembly - avalonedit via nu-get results in error

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, avalonedit

I have stumbled upon an issue where downloading AvalonEdit through nuget to my project would result in:

**"Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit, PublicKeyToken=9cc39be672370310' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."**

What I have tried so far:

1. Uninstall/reinstall lib via nuget
2. Download the library from web source and manually add it to my project
3. Crosschecked namespace/dependency that could be related to the lib

So nothing helped, there is one possibility that the lib it self require some missing 3rd party assembly, but documentation does not state that and the runtime exception has no info regarding that apart the error I have pasted above. Any help/ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an actual cause: I have added a nuget package only for library project in which the dependency is used (.dll), but did not include it in my startup project (.exe). After **installing the dependency on main project** everything started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the project worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).